# Keep getting an error when I try to push a directory with Terraform files into a remote GitHub Repo

Tags: github, terraform, git-lfs

On a local GitHub repo, I have a directory called "s3" that contains a Terraform file for creating an AWS S3 Bucket remotely. When I try pushing the directory onto my remote repo, I keep getting this error.

```
$ git push origin repo
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1/1), 1.3 KB | 0 B/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 22, done.
Counting objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 50.31 MiB | 1.12 MiB/s, done.
Total 21 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), completed with 1 local object.
remote: error: Trace: 2bcd19423f0176b3048b9144f26779fab7c903f263a60b8534632e7c697ec700
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File s3/.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/3.74.3/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v3.74.3_x5.exe is 244.70 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To github.com:User/Remote-Repo.git
! [remote rejected] repo -> repo (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:User/Remote-Repo.git'
```

I have `git lfs` installed which should help with pushing files with large sizes, but it isn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: Some names in the error have been edited for privacy/security.

Comment: One query here, why are you trying to push .terraform folder into git repo? Usually .terraform folder is auto created when we run "terraform init" and it will have size of about 200-300MB files. I guess you should add terraform entry in .gitignore file and give a try

Comment: You didn't mark the terraform files as "large" files that should not be stored in Git. However, as @TapanHegde said, you probably should not be storing these files at all.